# Условие для ссылки

Tags: php

Есть условие: если админ, то в аккаунте видна ссылка mail, если не админ, то не видна.
Как с этим условием это организовать?

```
if (has_access($session_user_id, 1) === true)
```

Comment: А теперь по-русски и более подробно.

Comment: а я что по арабски написал? 

есть админка, есть файл mail.php его надо туда втулить что бы не по url переходить по нему, есть обычные пользователи, как сделать что бы mail была только в админском аккаунте

Comment: Просто для информации: защита на уровне URL не самая лучшая затея.

ЗЫ: никто вам вразумительного ответа не даст, ибо никто не знает как у вас устроен проект. если тупо выводится html то:

if (has_access($session_user_id, 1) === true) {
echo '<a href="mail.php?...">mail</a>';
}

Comment: что такое has_access откуда берется переменная `$session_user_id`

кто что возвращает и прочее.

А то выглядит как: Есть машина, водители разные, как узнать по радиусу колеса сколько она может проехать на литре бензина.

Comment: все вопрос решен, надо было именно так и вводить)
if (has_access($session_user_id, 1) === true) { echo '<a href="mail.php?...">mail</a>'; }

Comment: меня интересовало только как сделать так что бы mail была видна только админу, has_access это функция, $session_user_id это переменная, это условие если 1 то админ и выводится ADMIN ну это совершенно в других файлах, но тем ни мение вопрос решен большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function has_access($session_user_id,$page_id){
   $res = mysql_query('select `user_access` from `access` where `user_id`='.$session_user_id.' and `page_id`='.$page_id);
  $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);
  return $row->user_access;
}
```

Не понял вопрос.

Comment: надо было что бы в админке mail было видно а другим пользователям нет, это скорее html чем php но уже все организовал!